# Why is "you all" contracted to "y'all" and not "you'll"?

Tags: contractions, you-all

Is you'll also valid in the context of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsfnuyyjaB0)?  Or is viper just setting new rules down in the English language?

Comment: Just wait until [The Academy](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html) gets to hear about this. Promulgating rules without a poetic license!

Comment: "You'll" is not pronounced anywhere close to "you all" *and* it already means "you will", so it's dead on arrival.

Comment: "y'll" is an Americanism.

Comment: @TrevorD: I wouldn't label it as an Americanism – in the U.S., _y'all_ is mostly used in the South.

Comment: What he ***says*** (sings? cantillates?) is clearly the term conventionally spelled **y'all**. Why he (or his label) chooses to spell this *you'll* is beyond speculation. ... @TrevorD The artist is from Arkansas.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks. I wasn't aware of the spelling, nor that it is used only in parts of USA.

Comment: @TrevorD _Y’ll_ looks more like a Welshism!

Comment: It's the way it's pronounced.  "You'll" is pronounced "yule".  "Y'all" is pronounced "yawl".

Answer (score 3):

Compare:
[you'll](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/you-ll) [*you will*] /juːl/
*you will*: The longer vowel is on the former word: (y)**ou**, so the contraction retains it and drops the shorter vowel sound (w) **i** ll – ***you'll***.

[y'all](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/y-all) [*you all*]  /jɔːl/
*you all*: The longer vowel is on the latter word: **a**(ll), so the contraction retains it and drops the shorter vowel sound (y) **ou** – ***y'all***.

Comment: Incidentally, the lyrics seem to also use "I sold my soul to satan but bought it back from god with this song\ **Ya'll** ...", "**Y'all** falling off like the last century" and "**y'all** haters feelings hurt".

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is because *you'll* is already a contraction for *you will*.

Answer (score -1):

*You'll* is short for *you will*, as emily has said. *Ya'll*, I have heard from grammatically correct Southern friends, was a version of *you*, while *all y'all* was the form for *you all* (i.e. plural).

But either way, the sooner this thing dies from the English language, the better.

Comment: It will _NEVER_ die. Your hope is vain.

Comment: Hope springs eternal! D:<

Comment: English changes over time, viper is eternal.  There's also other classics by viper, like [I'm Rich Already 4 Life (Too Late to Hate)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnGAFHgVZr8)